# How to read data from a serial port and write it to a file

Tags: c, serial-port, fwrite

I have code written that opens a serial port and also opens a txt log file. I want to write incoming data on the serial port to the log file. My question is how to I or what is the best way to read data from the serial port and write it to a file. I can post the code that opens the serial port and log file if its necessary but I don't want to clutter my questions.

I currently have a while loop which reads data from the serial port into a 32 element char array and then writes it to the file. However, the file contains garbage because it is writing the buffer continuously to the file.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to do this properly. I should really only write when the buffer is full but how do I know what size the buffer should be and what happens if there are buffer overruns for example if I don't read on time.

```
int i,rdlen, ptr;
char buf[32];

while( 1 ) {

    rdlen = read(fd_serial_port, &buf[ptr], 1); //read data from serial line into buffer

    fwrite(buf , 1 , sizeof(buf) , log_file);

    fflush(log_file);

}
```

The data coming in from the serial line looks like this and arrives every 2 seconds (if that matters)

```
Starting Contiki-1cb08a4
With DriverLib v0.44336
TI SmartRF06EB + CC26xx EM
 Net: sicslowpan
 MAC: TSCH2
 RDC: nordc
 RF: Channel 25
[node] id=0, role=6ln
```

Comment: What's your specific problem? Read the documentation of the functions, your sender on the serial line and write the code. Avoid undefined behaviour using common practice. If you don't know what that is, read the basics in a good textbook.

Comment: *"I can post the code that opens the serial port and log file if its necessary but ..."* -- Since proper termios configuration of the serial terminal is crucial for functionality, you do need to post that code, or otherwise overlook a cause of your issues.  And what little you have posted is either too sparse or full of errors.  *"I currently have a while loop which reads data from the serial port ..."* -- This hints at part of the problem.  You fail to distinguish what type of data: is it binary or text (i.e. should you be using raw or canonical mode)?  The sample looks like text.

Comment: *"I should really only write when the buffer is full ..."* -- That can reduce syscall overhead.  BUT your buffer is a measly 32 bytes (in comparison to a 512 byte sector), and the **read()** from the serial terminal is for just one byte.  So sycall overhead for this code is excessive compared to what is could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard idiom is:

```
rdlen = read(fd_serial_port, buf, sizeof(buf));
fwrite(buf, 1, rdlen, log_file);
```

When you read, you want to tell `read` that it's allowed to read up to `sizeof(buf)` (that is, 32) characters into `buf`.  And then, when you call `fwrite`, you want to tell it to write only as many characters as you just read (i.e., `rdlen`).

In this way, you use `buf` over and over again, to read and write one chunk (up to 32 bytes) of data at a time.  You don't need to keep track of a pointer into `buf` or anything; you just need to track how many characters you got each time through the loop -- which is your `rdlen` variable. But you don't need those `i` and `ptr` variables.

Also, you might want to test for end of file / error and break out of the loop if that happens:

```
if(rdlen <= 0) break;
```

Also, you don't necessarily need that `fflush` call.

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful reply.

Comment: *"you might want to test for end of file"* -- No such thing for a serial terminal.

Comment: @sawdust Well, (a) I did say "might", (b) I did say "end of file / error", (c) a serial port *can* report end-of-file under some circumstances (think: control-D under Unix), and (d) it's a standard idiom, in which I think it's a good idea to get in the habit of checking for EOF even when it "can't happen".  But other than that, you're right, no such thing.